# Migrating Comments to Chat Off Topic(words of warning, short)

Tags: discussion, comments, chat, off-topic, site-crossover

Apologies for the rough edit, but it's too much work at this point to put it back the way it was. and the original post really was too long anyway.

The reason for this post basically boils down to the contents of [my post on anesthesia](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18814/15555), it's corresponding [chat migrated comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90934/discussion-on-question-by-kipbits-why-is-it-called-conscious-sedation), and [an associated post in med sci meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1055/15555). I've been informed that the chat contents will eventually be automatically deleted once the necessary time period has elapsed, after which it will no longer be possible to read what was said. So i suppose i'll attempt to summarize the gist here:

To be brief, my post was about why a type of procedural anesthesia called conscious sedation has its name. Because in all likelihood the patient will be asleep or at least not remember the procedure. During the comments(later migrated to chat), i had it initially explained to me that this was because the drugs given to me were designed to interfere with my long-term memory. This seamed like magic; how is long-term memory just switched off without interfering with working memory? It was then explained to me that the drugs used give a similar effect to being fall-down/blackout drunk. Therefore, I think a more accurate and honest name for this type of sedation should be blackout drunk sedation. It's kind of besides the point though as I was supposed to have only local anesthesia, but they changed it on me last minute. It probably would have been better not to have had the surgery at all.

Long story short, I had surgery and things did not go to plan. I think it's important to remember that hospitals are dangerous places, and enter at your own peril. Also, scrutinize your doctor and watch out for funny lingo that doesn't mean what you think it should.

The body heals itself ...but everyone gets old eventually

Comment: `but the issue I have is that some of the comments that were moved were relevant to further clarification of the question`
You could edit your question to include the helpful comments.

Comment: None of the comments were deleted. They were all moved to chat intact.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see anything problematic here.

> Just to be clear I am only talking about saving the first 5 comments (not all that long), so the issue is just whether or not they deserve to be lumped in with an off-topic chat?

The first five comments had already drifted into personal advice. If there's valuable information added in your comments, **edit it into the question** - you still have it preserved in chat. If there's valuable information in Bryan's comments that constitutes an answer, encourage him to write an answer.

Users on our sites should not expect to *need* to read comments in order to get the full picture of a question. They should be able to ignore the comments section entirely and be able to do a credible job answering. So, edit in any information!

> **Should these comments have been moved?** And is there a process to restore them at this point?

Yes, they should have. There's no real need to leave some of them behind in most cases. They can be undeleted in this case as any comment deleted by a moderator can be undeleted but I don't see a reason to.

> Perhaps what I'm really trying to get at is, **does it really help Stack Exchange to have links to long off-topic chats? Why not just delete the part where it went off topic?**

We make these chat rooms as a courtesy. Chat is a great place to build community and encourage collaboration. We think that discussions are great things to have on our sites - in the right place (chat) - so we don't necessarily want to quash them unless they're outright abusive. So, we give you a place to move the conversation - the UI even allows you to create a chat room yourself after a certain number of exchanged messages.

Mods can absolutely just delete the comments if they wish. They make that choice frequently on their sites. As a moderator I deleted thousands of comments on the site I moderated in less than a year and moved few of them to chat.

Your mod likely felt that retaining the discussion was worth it. Alternately, deleting the comments outright often creates complaints of their own - users upset their discussion was deleted entirely. So sometimes moving to chat is a way of avoiding that.

---

I can confirm that none of the comments are missing. Twelve were removed and twelve were transferred into chat. I can't speak to why you remember a comment that you didn't post but there was neither an error nor any duplicity on the part of the moderators here.

Comment: @kipbits As I said before, there's nothing wrong with your question. Quit focusing on the comments. I'm afraid you may actually have deterred people from answering because you've made such an issue about it that they don't want to get tangled up in the drama.