# Why is my question no longer added to Top Questions (minimum reputation points to comment and chat)?

Tags: support, edits, homepage

Why is [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325220/migrating-comments-to-chat-to-continue-off-topic-preserve-on-topic-comments) no longer added to [Top Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com) when I edit/update it?

I have just edited it, but it is no longer visible in the list. I see other questions with negative votes high on the Top Questions list. Why is my question no longer updating? Is this a bug? It was updating properly a couple hours ago... why not now? **How is the Top Questions list compiled?**

I kind of like my question and want it to be seen...

#### Addition (please do not downvote)

I am adding this disclaimer here because I think people are forgetting something as demonstrated by the comment below that goes as follows:

> You could have asked someone on chat [a]bout this and I'm sure they would have explained without downvoting a perfectly legitimate question

At the time this comment was written I had 1 reputation point and was unable to comment or chat since there are minimum requirements for these privileges:

- **minimum to comment = 5**
- **minimum to chat = 20**

#### Update:

As of writing my rep has improved, and perhaps I will participate in chats once I have received sufficient rep...

Comment: It's listed, just not where you're looking at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active. Basically it's hidden as it reached -8 score, the threshold for being kicked out of the homepage, rationale being that if the community doesn't like it, probably best not to showcase it. Searching for the dupe...

Comment: FWIW it's still visible [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active), just not on the front of the homepage that everyone sees most often.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle not too familiar with Meta's conventions but isn't it wrong to edit out the [bug] tag? You and I know it's not one, but future searchers might be looking for a similar problem in the [bug] tag? Basically respecting OP's state of mind at the time of putting them, and writing a "it's not a bug" answer instead?

Comment: @Jenayah I actually [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323127/is-it-okay-to-edit-by-design-bug-reports-into-support-questions) exactly that. It seems the consensus is that it's okay to edit them into support questions if they're obviously by design. Also, I think that, in this case, most people would search for this with [support] rather than [bug].

Comment: @SupaMega alright, nice to kknow :)

Comment: has my question been locked? I can no longer edit it...

Comment: @kipbits If it were locked, you wouldn't be able to comment on it. What error message do you see?

Comment: oh thanks! meta is giving me double vision

Comment: still it would be nice if every time i said something I did not get **quite so many down-votes**

Comment: It's a tough "forum", you need to check for duplicates before posting. You could have asked someone on chat bout *this* and I'm sure they would have explained without downvoting a perfectly legitimate question. A question I asked myself when I first saw it happened to me but I didn't post a question, (too embarrassed, I guess) so I searched for the answer until I found an explanation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA you are forgetting the minimum 20 rep points to participate in chat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it has a score of -8 and it's on a meta site:

> The "home page" of a Stack Exchange site will filter out all questions that fall below a certain threshold. This is -4 score for main Q&A sites, and -8 for Meta sites. This is because the home page is meant to highlight quality content, so that a brand new visitor will see good stuff. —[Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99932/323179)